# Why `foldl1` runs out of memory yet `foldr1` works just fine?

Tags: haskell

I wrote `last` function by using `foldl1` and `foldr1`.

```
lastr :: [a] -> a
lastr = foldr1 (flip const)

lastl :: [a] -> a
lastl = foldl1 (flip const)
```

They just work fine for short lists. But when I tried with a very long list, [1..10^8], lastr returns the solution in 6.94 sec yet lastl ran out of memory.

Definition of foldr1 and foldl1 are (to my understanding)

```
foldr1 f [x] = x
foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x $ foldr1 f xs
```

and

```
foldl1 f [x] = x
foldl1 f (x:y:ys)=foldl1 f $ f x y : ys
```

Seen from these, foldl1 seems to use less memory than foldr1 because foldr1 needs to keep an expression like `f x1 $ f x2 $ f x3 $ f x4 $...` while foldl1 can just calculate `f x y` everytime and store it as a head element of a list in stead of holding it until it gets to 10^8.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my argument?

Comment: foldl is lazy, foldr is strict, try $ fold1' http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:foldl1-39-

Comment: @DiegoNolan `foldr` is not strict. It's a lot more lazy than `foldl` depending on how you measure laziness.

Comment: `(flip const) x y` is just `y`. There is nothing to accumulate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The right fold can start producing immediately if the combining function is lazy in its second argument. A simplistic example:

```
foldr1 (++) ["one", "two", "three", ...]
    ~> "one" ++ foldr1 (++) ["two", "three", ...]
```

and the first part of the result is immediately accessible without further evaluating the second argument of `(++)`. That needs only be evaluated when the first part is consumed. Often, the first part can then already be garbage-collected.

In the example with `f = flip const` as the combining function, we have a different situation, that is strict<sup>(1)</sup> in its second argument, but doesn't need to evaluate it at all. And it ignores its first. That is also good for right folds. Here it goes

```
foldr1 f [x1, x2, x3, ... ]
    ~> f x1 (foldr1 f [x2, x3, ... ])
```

and now the outermost `f` can immediately evaluated

```
    ~> foldr1 f [x2, x3, ... ]
    ~> f x2 (foldr1 f [x3, ... ])
    ~> foldr1 f [x3, ... ]
```

and at each step, the outermost `f` can always be immediately evaluated (completely), and one list element thrown away.

If the list is given by a generator that can create it in constant space when sequentially consumed,

```
last = foldr1 (flip const)
```

can run in constant space.

With the left fold, things are different. Since that is tail-recursive

```
foldl1 f (x:y:zs) = foldl f x (y:zs) = foldl f (f x y) zs
```

it cannot return anything before the fold has reached the end of the list. In particular, a left fold can never terminate on an infinite list.

Now, looking at our case `f = flip const`, we find

```
foldl1 f [x1, x2, x3, x4, ...]
    ~> foldl f x1 [x2, x3, x4, ... ]
    ~> foldl f (f x1 x2) [x3, x4, ... ]
    ~> foldl f (f (f x1 x2) x3) [x4, ... ]
```

Of course it would be possible to immediately evaluate `f x1 x2` to `x2`, and then `f x2 x3 = x3`, but that is only possible for this special `f`.

Since `foldl` is a general higher order function, it cannot evaluate the intermediate results before they are needed, since it is possible that the intermediate results never are needed - and in fact, they are never needed here, at the end of the list, one gets an expression

```
f (f (f (f ...y3) y2) y1) y0
   ~> y0
```

and then the outermost `f` can be evaluated without looking at the huge thunk of nested `f`s that builds the first argument.

`foldl` (resp. `foldl1`) cannot know that it would have been far more efficient to evaluate the intermediate results immediately.

The strict left folds, `foldl'` and `foldl1'` do that, they evaluate the intermediate results to weak head normal form (to the outermost value constructor or lambda), and

```
last = foldl1' (flip const)
```

would also be very efficient.

But, since the intermediate results are evaluated further than with `foldr`, they would be a little less efficient, and, importantly, if any list element is `⊥`, the `foldl1'` version would return `⊥`:

```
foldl1' f [x1, ⊥, x3, x4]
    ~> foldl' f x1 [⊥, x3, x4]
    ~> case f x1 ⊥ of
          pattern    -- that causes ⊥
   ~> ⊥
```

whereas the `foldr1` version has no problem with that, since it doesn't inspect the list elements or intermediate results at all.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> That `f` is strict in its second argument means that

```
f x ⊥ = ⊥
```

Since `f` simply returns its second argument, that is evidently the case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer! I learned a lot (including why foldr could work for infinite lists)! I have not studied modules and stuff, so I do not have foldl1'. Is it possible to implement foldl1' only with Prelude functions? Also, what do you mean by `⊥`? I have never seen that character. Again, thank you very much for your great answer!

Comment: You can implement `foldl1'` with only `Prelude` functions, what you need is `seq`. It's easier to just `import Data.List` to get it (and `foldl'`), though. `foldl' f z = lgo z where lgo x [] = x; lgo x (y:ys) = let w = f x y in w `seq` lgo w ys` is pretty much how `foldl'` is defined, then `foldl1' f (x:xs) = foldl' f x xs` gives you `foldl1'`. These definitions do not force the evaluation of the initial value, if that is desired, one needs to add a `seq` for that. `⊥` is "bottom", a symbol denoting nonterminating computations/undefined/errors.